# how the hypothesis test of binomial distribution can be modified if parameter $p$ is unknown?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Explain how the test would be modified if the hypothesis to be tested that from your sample data is from a binomial distribution with the parameter $p$ unknown.
.
.
I think we can use $z$-score for the two-tailed test right?

Comment: In testing a hypothesis about binomial $p,$ _of course_ $p$ is unknown. The issue what you want to test. Is there context you're not sharing?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to assume p = 0.5 for a proportion z test and write null as being not significantly different to 0.5 and alternate as significantly different. You have no other reference to compare.